# Update pagination value by onclick with a drop down box and PHP

Tags: php, onclick

Hi I have a drop down box, which I use to control the value of pagination for my MYSQL results, this works fine, but i want to do is remove the button and have the value update through onclick.  I am a newbie to javascript and not sure if this is possible? so any suggestions that i can explore would be appreciated.

This is my working php and select box.

HTML

```
 <form name="form1" method="GET" action="pagination_test.php">
   <label for="pagination"></label>
    <select name="pagination" id="pagination">
     <option value="10">10 Items Per Page</option>
     <option value="20">20 Items Per Page</option>
     <option value="30">30 Items Per Page</option>
     <option value="40">40 Items Per Page</option>
     <option value="50">50 Items Per Page</option>
     <option value="75">75 Items Per Page</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
 </form
```

And the PHP

```
 $pagination = $_GET['pagination'];
   if(isset($_GET['pagination'])) {
     $limit = "$pagination"; 
       } else {
     $limit = 30; 
       }

    echo "$limit";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

Include jQuery in the `<head>` of your page.  Something like:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this somewhere below the jQuery library:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pagination').change(function() {
            $('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You shouldn't need to change the `<form>`.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, so simple, but i ahve spent ages looking through Google and found nothing.  So really appreciated.  Thanks you